# solution similar to include_graphics that works inside div

Tags: html, r-markdown, knitr, htmltools

**I'm trying to determine the best way to include png images inside multiple nested divs within R markdown.**

I would love to use `knitr::include_graphics()` but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work inside a div.

for example...

lets say I want to create side by side images with two png images.

I would love to use the method below. However, it does not generate the png's properly.

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)

div(
div(class="col-md-6", include_graphics("image1.png")),
div(class="col-md-6", include_graphics("image2.png")),
class="row"
)
```

I'm aware of using things like `readPNG` with `grid.raster` but don't find they are as useable as `knitr::include_graphics()` which seems to render better in Rmarkdown.

Is anyone familiar with any alternatives to `knitr::include_graphics` or `grid.raster(readPNG())`?

I am also aware of the native knitr way of including images e.g. `![](www/image1.png)` but have not found a way to include this inside many nested HTML divs. And writing raw html e.g. `<img>` doesn't recognize the file as an external one, and won't export properly.

Does anyone have any thoughts?